# SSO - Share single User table between several websites or somehow keep multiple User tables in sync?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, single-sign-on

I'm working on a single sign-on solution for two ASP.NET MVC3 websites. The sites are on separate subdomains. I'm using Forms Authentication and so far I everything is working well. When I sign into a.example.com I'm automatically signed in to b.example.com too. Nice.

Each application has its own database.

My question is this - if I want to keep certain user information in sync between the two sites (say the last activity date or some user preference) then should I have a User table in both databases and somehow keep them in sync or should only a.example.com's database have a User table and b.example.com somehow reads and writes to it?

Thanks for your advice.

**Edit:** Thanks to adam I'm leaning towards storing all user data in a separate database. I will pass the authenticated user's username and ID to each application in the authentication cookie. Can anybody offer any advice around maintaining referential integrity between the two databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most SSO solutions I've seen have a central `accounts` portal where users can maintain settings, change email address etc.

Think Google:

- google.com/reader
- google.com/analytics
- google.com/accounts

This represents a single user store, providing authentication to several sites. This has various benefits, such as a single place to store session hashes and other security details (for preventing things like man-in-the-middle attacks).

In a true SSO, an authentication request redirects to the central auth system (ie google.com/accounts), authenticates and then redirects to the service that requested authentication.

From your description, it sounds like you have separate authentication for each site/service, but the user db is shared.

Comment: Thanks adam - I should have been clearer. All of the authentication happens at a.example.com. b.example.com redirects to a.example.com/logon?referrer=b.example.com whenever the user needs to be authenticated. Once authenticated I check the 'referrer' value and redirect them back to where they came from.

Comment: I like the idea of a central "accounts" portal/site that takes care of authentication and user settings etc. Are you suggesting that I should create a third database to hold my User data that each of the other websites can access?

Comment: Yes - we have a central `sso` db with a `users` table. We then have a `services` table, describing each service (base url, etc). There is a link table between `users` and `services` which *enables* the relevant services for each user.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. Thanks Adam. Just one more question if I may - what about relationships in the a.example.com database (for example an UpdatedBy column in a Company table)? Should I use the UserID or the Username for UpdatedBy (I can easily get username from the auth cookie)? What happens to the relationship when a User is deleted from the SSO DB?

Comment: That depends on your specific needs - something I can't really answer. But storing the username in a cookie is a bad idea - store a salted hash. If I've answered your original question, could you accept it? Thanks